# Using Flask-SQLAlchemy without Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I had a small web service built using `Flask` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy` that only held one model. I now want to use the same database, but with a command line app, so I'd like to drop the `Flask` dependency.

My model looks like this:

```
class IPEntry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ip_address = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True)
    first_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(),
        default = datetime.datetime.utcnow
    )
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(),
        default = datetime.datetime.utcnow
    )

    @validates('ip')
    def validate_ip(self, key, ip):
        assert is_ip_addr(ip)
        return ip
```

Since `db` will no longer be a reference to `flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)`, how can I convert my model to use just SQLAlchemy. Is there a way for the two applications (one with `Flask-SQLAlchemy` the other with `SQLAlchemy`) to use the same database?

Comment: The *database* should be independent of the *models* or ORM layer you're using.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I'm looking for a way to reuse code in both flask and non flask without having to change my model definitions in any significant way.

Comment: There's nothing flask-related in your model. All you need is to create a db connection and import your model to either flask, or non-flask app. I'd simply put the model in 'models.py' so (really just move the above from the flask main .py file and import/instantiate IPentry when needed).

Answer (score 12):

you can do this to replace `db.Model`:

```
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy as sa

base = declarative_base()
engine = sa.create_engine(YOUR_DB_URI)
base.metadata.bind = engine
session = orm.scoped_session(orm.sessionmaker())(bind=engine)

# after this:
# base == db.Model
# session == db.session
# other db.* values are in sa.*
# ie: old: db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('s.id'))
#     new: sa.Column(sa.Integer,sa.ForeignKey('s.id'))
# except relationship, and backref, those are in orm
# ie: orm.relationship, orm.backref
# so to define a simple model

class UserModel(base):
    __tablename__ = 'users' #<- must declare name for db table
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(255),nullable=False)
```

then to create the tables:

```
 base.metadata.create_all()
```

Answer (score 5):

That is how to use SQLAlchemy without Flask (for example to write a bulk of objects to PostgreSQL database):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Define variables DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME   
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}: 
{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'

# ----- This is related code -----
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
# ----- This is related code -----

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table_name'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String)

objects = [MyModel(id=0, value='a'), MyModel(id=1, value='b')]
session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
session.commit()
```

Comment: I don’t think the question was related to bulk inserts

Comment: @KyleRoux bulk insert is just a simple example to make a reproducible code. The related part is 6 lines on top where I create an engine. I spent quite a lot of time to make it working without Flask this way, so not sure why you think it is not relevant :/

Answer (score 3):

Check this one [github.com/mardix/active-alchemy](https://github.com/mardix/active-alchemy)

> Active-Alchemy is a framework agnostic wrapper for SQLAlchemy that makes it really easy to use by implementing a simple active record like api, while it still uses the db.session underneath. Inspired by Flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: Wow, this wrapper was worked perfectly for my models. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The sqlalchemy docs has a good [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) with examples that sound like what you want to do.

Shows how to connect to a db, mapping, schema creation, and querying/saving to the db.

Comment: Should update the link though... https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article about Flask-SQLAlchemy: how it works, and how to modify models to use them outside of Flask:

http://derrickgilland.com/posts/demystifying-flask-sqlalchemy/

Comment: This is a great link but is currently broken/down.  https://web.archive.org/web/20190530064812/http://derrickgilland.com/posts/demystifying-flask-sqlalchemy/ can help

Answer (score 0):

Flask (> 1.0) attempt to provide helpers for sharing code between an web application and a command line interface; i personally think it might be cleaner, lighter and easier to build libraries unbound to flask, but you might want to check:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/cli/
- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.cli

Comment: Both these links currently appear to be broken.

Comment: @holdenweb < links to the official documentation fixed, thank you for reporting

Comment: They're down again.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/cli/ takes out the version so it should work as long as cli is supported...

Answer (score 0):

This does not completely answer your question, because it does not remove Flask dependency, but you can use `SqlAlchemy` in scripts and tests by just *not running* the Flask app.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

test_app = Flask('test_app')
test_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'database_uri'
test_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

metadata = MetaData(schema='myschema')
db = SQLAlchemy(test_app, metadata=metadata)

class IPEntry(db.Model):
    pass
```

One difficulty you may encounter is the requirement of using `db.Model` as a base class for your models if you want to target the web app and independent scripts using same codebase. Possible way to tackle it is using *dynamic polymorphism* and wrap the class definition in a function.

```
def get_ipentry(db):
    class IPEntry(db.Model):
        pass
    return IPEntry
```

As you construct the class run-time in the function, you can pass in different `SqlAlchemy` instances. Only downside is that you need to call the function to construct the class before using it.

```
db = SqlAlchemy(...)
IpEntry = get_ipentry(db)
IpEntry.query.filter_by(id=123).one()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create database and table

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

if os.path.exists('test.db'):
    os.remove('test.db')

Base = declarative_base()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

## Using Flask_SQLAlchemy directly

```py
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app, metadata=MetaData())


class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())


person = Person(name='Bob')
db.session.add(person)
db.session.commit()
print(person.id)
```